# Some clarifications and a question on basic probability.

Tags: probability, statistics, problem-solving

I have a few questions and some clarifications.

CLARIFICATIONS:
1. Assume we roll 2 four sided dice. What is P({sum of the rolls is even})? I answered the question correctly

I: Odd + Odd = Even
J: Even + Even = Even
K: Odd + Even = Odd

I answered the question with this line of thinking P(I) + P(J):

P(I) = (2 / 4) * (2 / 4) P(J) = (2 / 4) * (2 / 4)
= 1 / 2

*Is this a valid concept of solving the problem?
2. Assume we roll 2 four sided dice. What is P({first roll larger than second roll})?

P(1,<2,3,4>) + P(2, <3,4>) + P(3, 4)

(1 / 4 * 3 / 4) + (1 / 4 * 2 / 4) + (1 / 4 * 1 / 4) = 3 / 8

*Is this a valid concept of solving the problem? Are there better solutions?

QUESTION:

Say you're in a classroom with 29 other students (30 total students). What is the calculated probability that two students share the same birthdate? For simplicity, assume there are 365 days in a year and all birthdates are equally probable. I need help on this one.

Comment: You have asked several unrelated questions here.  It is considered bad manners to do so in a single post.  In any case, the birthday problem at the end is a famous one, which you can do a simple google search on, the solution deals with calculating the probability that *all students have different birthdays* (the opposite of what you are interested in).  For the first problem, notice that *whatever* you rolled on the first die, half of the possibilities on the second die will make the sum even, and the other half will make it odd.

Comment: In this case, since the first two problems were thoroughly worked out using similar methods and the question is whether the methods are correct, I would say those two questions are appropriate to ask together. But they _could_ have been asked separately, and I agree that the third part (birthdays) _should_ have been asked separately.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is correct.  Your notation could use some work.

You are partitioning the event into a series of disjoint events, whose individual probabilities you can calculate and then sum using the Law of Total Probability.  That is exactly the approach you should use.

> 1. Assume we roll 2 four sided dice. What is P({sum of the rolls is even})? I answered the question correctly

Let $X$ be the result of one die and $Y$ be the result of the other.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(\mathrm{Even}(X+Y)) & = \mathsf P(\mathrm{Even}(X))\;\mathsf P(\mathrm{Even}(Y))+\mathsf P(\mathrm{Odd}(X))\;\mathsf P(\mathrm{Odd}(Y))
\\[2ex] & = \frac 2 4 \frac 2 4 + \frac 2 4\frac 2 4
\\[2ex] & = \frac 1 2
\end{align}$$

Alternatively you can just notice that whatever result of the first dice, half of the results of the second dice will give an even sum.

> 2. Assume we roll 2 four sided dice. What is P({first roll larger than second roll})?

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(X > Y) & = \sum_{x=2}^4 \mathsf P(X=x) \mathsf P(Y< x)
\\[2ex] & = \mathsf P(X=2)\mathsf P(Y<2) + \mathsf P(X=3)\mathsf P(Y<3) + \mathsf P(X=4)\mathsf P(Y< 4)
\\[2ex] & = \frac 1 4 \left(\frac 1 4 + \frac 2 4 + \frac 3 4\right)
\\[1ex] & = \frac 3 8
\end{align}$$

> Say you're in a classroom with 29 other students (30 total students). What is the calculated probability that two students share the same birthdate? For simplicity, assume there are 365 days in a year and all birthdates are equally probable. I need help on this one.

In this case you need to use the Rule of Complements.   The sum of the probabilities of complementary events is $1$.   The event that "at least two students share a birthdate" is the complement of the event that "all students have unique birthdates".   Can you calculate the probability that nobody shares a birthdate?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification I appreciate it. I'm not that knowledgeable in the notation dept. but nonetheless I will try to improve. Is it right to say that the complement of the statement "all students have unique bdays" is "at least a pair of students have the same bday"? P({nobody shares a birthdate}) = (1 / 365) * (1 / 364) * (1 / 363)...(1 / 365 - 30)?

Comment: No, @JansenLopez .  That's the probability of picking specific dates out of a decreasing selection.  You don't care *which* birthday anyone has, just that each subsequent person has a *different* birthday. So the first person has $365$ options out of $365$, and each subsequent person has one less choice. $$\mathsf P(\text{no shared birthdays}) = \frac {365} {365}\cdot \frac {364}{365}\cdot\frac{353}{365}\cdots\frac{365-29}{365} = \frac{\binom{365}{30}30!}{365^{30}}$$

Comment: Thanks! I now totally get it. One last thing, is it right to say that the complement of the statement "all students have unique bdays" is "at least a pair of students have the same bday"?

Comment: Yes, and that is what you want to find. @JansenLopez